# MongoDB - query by combination of fields

Tags: mongodb, autocomplete, full-text-search, typeahead

For example, I have documents describing auditoriums. Each document in collection has at least two fields: `room` and `building`. In my UI I have auditoriums displayed like so: `room`-`building` (`room` concatenated with hyphen and with `building`).

I would like to implement a typeahead (autocompletion) with one field to search by described format. To illustrate, suppose we have two documents: `{ "room": "301", "building": "18" }` and `{ "room": "204", "building": "26" }`.

Querying by `26`, `-26`, `204-2` or `204-26` should return the second document.

`301`, `301-`, `301-1` or `301-18` query should return the first one.

How can I do this in MongoDB? I don't mind using text indexes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could store a third field in each document which is in the format `room-building`. Then add an index to this field and search off it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done on the front end, not on the database.

The best way is to query for all the possible `room-building` values and fill an array on the front end with `room-building` keys which map to `_id` values.

Then use something like the [jQuery autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) fed with an array of all the possible `room-building` values. When the user chooses a particular `room-building`, you can use the array to access the document `_id` to very quickly query for the data required for that auditorium.